# About Bluetooth LE Link Controller in esp32

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

When going through esp32 datasheet it been seen that there is wirless circuit section in the block diagram.
I am wondering how the bluetooth functionality is implemented in microcrontrollers like esp32.
Is it a hardware inside the Soc or whether it is memory region which contains the bluetooth stack.
from esp32 side Espressif has already pre-loaded the wireless protocol stacks for WiFi b, g, n, Bluetooth and BLE.
if anyone knows how in deep this works that where this wireless protocol stacks are implemented?
[image]

Need to know how this functionality is implemented on a microcontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espressif has bought RivieraWave's Bluetooth solution. It consists of a hardware block on the SoC, accessible through registers that are not mentioned in the datasheet or the technical reference, as well as a software part which is closed source (https://github.com/espressif/esp32c3-bt-lib), which communicate with the hardware through the mentioned registers.